# mimeapps.list is missing in ~/.local/share/applications

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I was trying to change my default file manager in Ubuntu 14.04 from Nautilus to spacefm. The procedure (that worked on a previous computer) is to add the following lines to ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:

```
inode/directory=spacefm.desktop
x-directory/normal=spacefm.desktop
```

On the current computer, there is no mimeapps.list, however. I created it myself (using touch mimeapps.list), but still nautilus opens when I double click a folder on my desktop.

Now you could help me with the following two questions:
1. Why don't I have the mimeapps.list?
2. How can I get spacefm (or any other installed file manager) to be the standard file manager?